# Python using re.match hangs with long text

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file with a list of domains, I want to use python regular expression to match domains and any subdomains.

Sample domains file

```
admin.happy.com
nothappy.com
```

I have the following regexp:

```
main_domain = 'happy.com'
mydomains = open('domains.txt','r').read().replace('\n',',')
matchobj = re.match(r'^(.*\.)*%s$' % main_domain,mydomains)
```

The code works fine for a short text, but when my domain file has 100+ entries it hangs and freezes.

Is there a way I can optimize the regexp to work with the content from the text file?

Comment: Pardon me. Are you looking for word happy.com in the list of domains? If yes, can't it be dong without regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(.*\.)*` most likely results in horrible backtracking. If the file contains one domain per line the easiest fix would be executing the regex on each line instead of the whole file at once:

```
main_domain = 'happy.com'
for line in open('domains.txt','r')):
    matchobj = re.match(r'^(.*\.)*%s$' % main_domain, line.strip())
    # do something with matchobj
```

If your file does not contain anything but domains in the format you posted you can even simplify this much more and not use a regex at all:

```
subdomains = []
for line in open('domains.txt','r')):
    line = line.strip()
    if line.endswith(main_domain):
        subdomains.append(line[:-len(main_domain)])
```

Comment: :). Its funny I added the comments asking why regex is needed and saw your answer.

Comment: "nothappy.com" is rejected by the regex (no dot) therefore `.endswith()` could used only to prefilter lines before applying the regex (and the regex should be changed)

Comment: `and line != main_domain` -> still no need for a regex

Comment: Nice second solution, could be briefer though: `with open('domains.txt', 'r') as f:\n    subdomains = [line[:-len(main_domain)] for line in f.read().splitlines() if line.endswith(main_domain)]` (with \n where newline should be)

Comment: to extract subdomains  without the regex you need to prefix `main_domain` with a dot `"."` e.g., `line.endswith("." + main_domain)`. You want to extract `a` from `a.happy.com`, you don't want to extract `not` from `nothappy.com`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid catastrophic backtracking, you could simplify the regex:

```
import re

with open("domains.txt") as file:
    text = file.read()
main_domain = "happy.com"
subdomains = re.findall(r"^(.+)\.%s$" % re.escape(main_domain), text, re.M)
```

If you want also to match the main domain: [`(r"^(?:(.+)\.)?%s$"`](http://ideone.com/tTj7O2).